# How to strip all array keys appended with :protected?

Tags: 7, entities, importing-exporting

I'm trying to replicate `entity->export()` using Entity Metadata Wrappers. When I call `value()` on entity_metadata_wrapped entities (in this case a field collection), I get everything `entity->export()` give me, plus a bunch of `entity_key:protected` fields. I'd like to strip these out, as everything not protected gives me identical values to that provided in export.

Example `wrapper->value()` result:

```
Object
(
    [fieldInfo:protected] => 
    [hostEntity:protected] => 
    [hostEntityId:protected] => 
    [hostEntityRevisionId:protected] => 
    [hostEntityType:protected] => 
    [langcode:protected] => und
    [item_id] => 9
    [revision_id] => 9
    [field_name] => field_treatment_categories
    [default_revision] => 1
    [archived] => 0
    [entityType:protected] => field_collection_item
    [entityInfo:protected] => Array
        (
            [label] => Field collection item
            [label callback] => entity_class_label
            [uri callback] => entity_class_uri
            [entity class] => FieldCollectionItemEntity
            [controller class] => EntityAPIController
            [base table] => field_collection_item
            [revision table] => field_collection_item_revision
            [fieldable] => 1
            [redirect] => 
            [entity keys] => Array
                (
                    [id] => item_id
                    [revision] => revision_id
                    [bundle] => field_name
                    [uuid] => uuid
                )

            [module] => field_collection
            [view modes] => Array
                (
                    [full] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Full content
                            [custom settings] => 
                        )

                    [token] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Tokens
                            [custom settings] => 
                        )

                )

            [access callback] => field_collection_item_access
            [metadata controller class] => FieldCollectionItemMetadataController
            [bundles] => Array
                (
                    [field_treatment_categories] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Field collection field_treatment_categories
                            [admin] => Array
                                (
                                    [path] => admin/structure/field-collections/%field_collection_field_name
                                    [real path] => admin/structure/field-collections/field-treatment-categories
                                    [bundle argument] => 3
                                    [access arguments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => administer field collections
                                        )

                                )

                            [rdf_mapping] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [field_treatments] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Field collection field_treatments
                            [admin] => Array
                                (
                                    [path] => admin/structure/field-collections/%field_collection_field_name
                                    [real path] => admin/structure/field-collections/field-treatments
                                    [bundle argument] => 3
                                    [access arguments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => administer field collections
                                        )

                                )

                            [rdf_mapping] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [static cache] => 1
            [field cache] => 1
            [load hook] => field_collection_item_load
            [translation] => Array
                (
                )

            [schema_fields_sql] => Array
                (
                    [base table] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => item_id
                            [1] => revision_id
                            [2] => field_name
                            [3] => archived
                            [4] => uuid
                        )

                    [revision table] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => revision_id
                            [1] => item_id
                        )

                )

            [token type] => field_collection_item
            [apachesolr] => Array
                (
                    [indexable] => 
                    [status callback] => 
                    [document callback] => 
                    [reindex callback] => 
                    [bundles changed callback] => 
                )

            [configuration] => 
            [uuid] => 1
        )

    [idKey:protected] => item_id
    [nameKey:protected] => item_id
    [statusKey:protected] => status
    [defaultLabel:protected] => 
    [uuid] => c1d3982f-31c8-4640-89b4-2f54334e4803
    [field_tc_short_description] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => short desc 2
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => short desc 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_tc_short_title] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Short title 2
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => Short title 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_tc_title] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Treatment Category 2
                            [format] => 
                            [safe_value] => Treatment Category 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [field_treatments] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 10
                            [revision_id] => 10
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 11
                            [revision_id] => 11
                        )

                )

        )

    [rdf_mapping] => Array
        (
        )

    [entity_view_prepared] => 1
)
```

The `[fieldInfo:protected]` fields I'd like to remove, but I haven't found an options/methods to do so. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking to do this, the answer is pretty simple.

entity_metadata_wrapper->value() returns an object, complete with protected properties. To get only the values from the result, you can use php's get_object_vars() function.

This returns data equivalent to a normal entity->export() call in terms of data, although I believe export returns JSON instead of the array you get here.

So:

```
// Wrap an existing entity.
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('entity_type', $entity);

// Get the object representation of that entity.
$entity_data = $wrapper->value();

// Strip all properties (including :protected), 
// and get an array representation of that data.
// This is the same data you get from entity->export(), 
// but in array form.
$final_data = get_object_vars($entity_data);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

use `array_walk` and scan the entity array to see if the `key` has the substring `:protected` in it. If yes, then `unset()` the array key.

Comment: While I am hoping for existing functionality, that's a good alternative. Cheers.

Comment: Because these were object properties, looping would not work to strip them out. You could use this method and construct a second array containing only the values foreach or array_walk can touch, providing a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because what you're seeing it's not an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), but an [object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php), so you can't simply unset protected properties, because they're **protected** for the reason.

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited classes.

This is how [PHP OOP visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) works. So you should find appropriate getter/setter method to change that member of class or extend that class and define one.